# How to pass boost::none to Python Quantlib

Tags: python, quantlib, quantlib-swig

This is linked to one of my earlier question:

[Quantlib passing a date vector to Schedule class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40770485/quantlib-passing-a-date-vector-to-schedule-class/40784105#40784105)

Basically, I have got everything working in C++. If I use Python, know how can I pass `boost::none` into a Python function?

Many thanks.

Comment: Just try passing `None`. Hopefully the wrapper layer translates it to `boost::none`. Otherwise you'd need Python bindings for boost :|

Comment: @Paul: Thanks for your suggestion. It doesn't work, but I think it might be due to the fact that I am using QuantLib_Python-1.6.1 instead of 1.8. Let me go and get an updated package to try it again.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you don't.  We still haven't exported that part of the interface to Python.

Comment: Is this still the case per QuantLib 1.16? Unable to pass `boost::none` from python?